# Innerjoin 2 Columns?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, subquery

I have 2 tables.

`dance_list` - table name

`type_of_dance` - column name (only has 1 column)

`motion_list` - table name

`type_of_motion` | `studio`

I've already inner-joined 2 columns to combine `type_of_motion` and `type_of_dance`. I call this new table `Physical`.

```
SELECT
    dan.*
FROM dance_list dan
Inner JOIN motion_list mot
    ON mot.type_of_motion like cast(dan.type_of_dance as varchar)
```

This displays the following:
`Type_of_dance`

Now, I want to display `Physical` with the column `studio_name` from the `type_of_dance` table.

I want it to look like:
`Type_of_dance` | `Studio_name`

What type of join would this be? I'm getting confused with joining a 2nd column onto an already innerjoined table. Thanks!

Comment: It's not clear what you want. Could you please make an attempt at writing the query, so we understand better what you want? Also, sample data and expected output would be a big help.

Comment: just add another inner join

Comment: `SELECT dan.type_of_dance, mot.studio ...`

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you successfully joined both tables already (otherwise, your query would return an empty resultset). You can then bring columns from any of the tables by simply expanding the `select` clause:

```
SELECT dan.type_of_dance, mot.studio
FROM dance_list dan
INNER JOIN motion_list mot
    ON mot.type_of_motion like cast(dan.type_of_dance as varchar)
```

The `join` condition sems more complicated that it needs to. For one, `like` without any wildcard on the right operand is equivalent to an equality check. Also, I suspect that you don't need to `cast` (this assumes that both columns are strings). This might be good enough:

```
SELECT dan.type_of_dance, mot.studio
FROM dance_list dan
INNER JOIN motion_list mot
    ON mot.type_of_motion = dan.type_of_dance
```

Finally: as your query stands, table `motion_list` has all the information you want already. Basically, the `join` simply filters `motion_list` on `type_of_motion`s that exist in `dance_list`. So you could phrase the query with `exists` instead, which makes the intent somehow clearer:

```
SELECT mot.*
FROM motion_list mot
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM dance_list dan WHERE dan.type_of_dance = mot.type_of_motion
)
```